# Lua undefined reference to `lua_newuserdata'

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to use Lua as an external library in a C++ project. However, I get the following error: "undefined reference to `lua_newuserdata' error: ld returner 1 exit status".

**My Setup:**

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
IDE: Code::Blocks 20.03
Compiler: GNU GCC Compiler

**Steps to Reproduce the Error:**

1. Create a new Code::Blocks project: File -> New -> Project -> Console Application -> C++ and finish the project creation;
2. Download the Lua binaries "lua-5.4.2_Linux54_64_lib.tar.gz" in the following address: https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.4.2/Linux%20Libraries/;
3. Extract the binaries in the Code::Blocks project folder. I have renamed the binaries folder as "lua542";
4. In Code::Blocks add the lua library to the linker settings: Settings -> Compiler -> Linker Settings. Then below "Link Libraries" click "Add" and choose the file "ProjectFolder/lua542/liblua54.a";
5. In "main.cpp" write the following minimum (not) working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lua.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::string cmd = "a = 7 + 11";

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    int r = luaL_dostring(L, cmd.c_str());
    lua_getglobal(L, "a");
    float a_in_cpp = (float)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    std::cout << "a_in_cpp = " << a_in_cpp << std::endl;
    lua_newuserdata(L, 1); // This line is problematic
    lua_newuserdatauv(L, 1, 1); // This line is also problematic
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

6. Try to compile and run the project.

**What have I tried**
I know the library was set correctly because the code works if the lines containing "lua_newuserdata" and "lua_newuserdatauv" are removed. Moreover, if I remove the library from the Linker Settings none of the Lua functions work.

Edit: I am not so sure about that anymore. If a try to compile the main.cpp file in a separate folder that does not contain the "liblua54.a" using the command
g++ main.cpp -o main -llua
I get a successful compilation (without the problematic function). It seems that my path has an older version of Lua. I will investigate that.

The function syntax seems to be correct according to the documentation in http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#8.3. And there is a macro to define the equivalence between the new function "lua_newuserdatauv" and its old version "lua_newuserdata".

I have found a similar problem in https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/1999. However, I don't know how to apply the suggested fix since I am not directly using the terminal to compile the code. Moreover, I can't see how my compiler could be getting an older version of Lua as suggested in that Issue, due to the test previously mentioned.

I also took a look in the following solutions here on Stack Overflow:

["Undefined reference to" using Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060009/undefined-reference-to-using-lua) The problem was caused by the absence of extern "C"{...}. However, I included "lua.hpp" which includes this wrap.

[Undefined reference to Lua C++ library functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832903/undefined-reference-to-lua-c-library-functions) It does not relate to my problem, since my tests have shown that the library is being linked to my project. My problem seems to be on that specific function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you included the correct `lua.hpp`? Because `lua_newuserdata` is a macro in Lua 5.4, it should be expanded by the preprocessor, the error indicates that the compiler treats it as a symbol, which makes no sense.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.
lua.hpp includes the other headers as follows:

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

Comment: I'm not asking you to check the content of the file, I mean you need to confirm that the path to the `lua.hpp` you included is correct. You may have multiple lua libraries on your system.

Comment: Oh. I understand now. Yes, this is probably the problem. If I execute, in a separate folder with the lua headers, the command

g++ -o main main.cpp -llua

I compile the program, even with no lua library in the folder. Therefore, it must be using another lualib in my system, which I am trying to locate and exclude in order to ensure that I am using the intended lua files that I have just downloaded.

Comment: You were absolutely right!
I deleted previous lualib versions of my machine. Then I notice that my project was using the header from the default locations, not the header on my project folder. When I pointed the correct header, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Shingo in a comment to the question, the cause of the problem was the compiler linking an older version of the lualib installed in the default folders of the system. This older version probably did not have the functions being used in the code.

The solution was to delete previous versions of the lualib from the default paths of the compiler/linker and then the correct version was used by the compiler/linker.

I appreciate Shingo help.

Answer (score 1):

`lua_newuserdata` is defined only if Lua is built with `LUA_COMPAT_5_3` option.
Sometimes Lua binaries are built with this option turned off, so you have to use `lua_newuserdatauv` instead.
It is simple: just use `0` for `nuvalue` parameter.

Comment: I had tried this. Even if a comment the line containing lua_newuserdata and keep only the line containing lua_newuserdatauv, with parameters (L, 1, 0), I keep getting an error:

Error: 'lua_newuserdatauv' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'lua_newuserdata'?